# Bevy setup fails because of foreign APIs/missing dependencies

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, bevy

I'm trying to set up Bevy 0.7.0 for the first time on Ubuntu 20.04, following the official guide on their website, and as soon as I configured it for fast compiles, it stopped compiling altogether. At first, it didn't find the clang linker, even though I had installed `lld` as instructed, but I solved that by installing the entire `clang` package. Then, after switching to the nightly channel, `cargo run` gave me this output:

```
   Compiling bevy-crevice-derive v0.7.0
error: Metal API enabled on non-Apple OS. If your project is not using resolver="2" in Cargo.toml, it should.
  --> /home/lenerdv/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/wgpu-hal-0.12.5/src/lib.rs:51:1
   |
51 | compile_error!("Metal API enabled on non-Apple OS. If your project is not using resolver=\"2\" in Cargo.toml, it should.");
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

error: DX12 API enabled on non-Windows OS. If your project is not using resolver="2" in Cargo.toml, it should.
  --> /home/lenerdv/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/wgpu-hal-0.12.5/src/lib.rs:53:1
   |
53 | compile_error!("DX12 API enabled on non-Windows OS. If your project is not using resolver=\"2\" in Cargo.toml, it should.");
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

followed by a bunch of `cannot find ___` and `undeclared crate ___` type errors (hundreds of them), and a final `type annotations needed` error ([full output](https://pastebin.com/uK6wECf5)). It's mainly complaining about `mtl`, so I'm guessing it might be a missing dependency, but I'm not sure as I'm quite new to rust.

Comment: `mtl` is for "Metal" which is an Apple API. So your problem isn't a missing dependency but a wrong configuration. Do you have `resolver="2"` in your `Cargo.toml` as per the compiler suggestion?

Comment: May also be relevant: https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/features.html#feature-resolver-version-2

Comment: Err... it worked. Smooth brain moment. Thanks!

Comment: @Jmb If you want to turn this into an answer, I'll be happy to accept it

Answer (score 1):

`mtl` stands for "Metal" which is an Apple API. So your problem isn't a missing dependency but a wrong configuration. This should be fixed by adding `resolver="2"` in your Cargo.toml as per the compiler suggestion.

For more details, see: https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/features.html#feature-resolver-version-2